# Точка входа в приложение C#

Tags: c#, winforms

Я пытаюсь прикрутить к текущему приложению, которое расположено на Form1 запуск Form2 в качестве заставки. Но при попытке скомпилировать всё это дело у меня появляется ошибка CS0017 (определено несколько точек входа для программы).

Понимаю, что точка входа у меня на Form1 в виде InitializeComponent();
Но не совсем понимаю что делать.

Вот код:

```
 static void Main()
    {
        {
            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);

            Form2 first = new Form2();
            DateTime end = DateTime.Now + TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5);
            first.Show();
            while(end>DateTime.Now)
            {
                Application.DoEvents();
            }
            first.Close();
            first.Dispose();
            Application.Run(new Form1()); 
        }
    }

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        start_game();
    }
```

Comment: Сколько у вас функций Main()?

Comment: Удали свой main.

Comment: Удалил, но Form2 от этого не запускается. Что я делаю не так?

Comment: _Понимаю, что точка входа у меня на Form1 в виде InitializeComponent();_ - точка входа это как раз функция `Main`

Answer (score -1):

Вы не там изменяете код. Form1 у вас запускается в **Main()**, который расположен в файле **Program.cs**, там вы можете изменить в код с Form1 на Form2 (последняя строчка метода).

Если Form2 используется как заставка, то в ней сделать загрузку всего необходимого и запустить Form1. Если она просто для красоты (судя по вашему коду), то можно просто использовать таймер и установить ему задержку, так как использовать цикл который вы написали плохо, из-за того, что он будет сильно нагружать процессор. В таймер напишите, что-то похоже:

```
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var mainForm = new Form2();
    Hide();
    ShowDialog();
    Close();
}
```